# error "Finder got an error: The operation can’t be completed because there is already an item with that name." number -48

Tags: applescript, backup

At work, I want to backup some Mac files to a Windows share and have created an AppleScript. It mounts the destination then creates a folder if it doesn't already exist. It then copies the contents of a local folder to this new folder on the destination. It then unmounts the destination

```
mount volume "smb://service.backup:<password>@server.domain.com/computer-backup"
set dest to result as alias
tell application "Finder"
    if not (exists POSIX file "/Volumes/server.domain.com/computer-backup/Web") then make new folder with properties {name:"Web"} at "computer-backup"
    duplicate items of folder "Macintosh HD:Library:Server:Web" to POSIX file "/Volumes/computer-backup/Web" with replacing
    eject dest
end tell
```

The mount is fine. But if the folder "Web" exists on the destination then it errors - despite the "if not (exists" statement. I have a very similar script at home (with different usernames, passwords and server addresses) which works fine. I am pretty sure I have had this working at work as well (hence the use of POSIX) but not anymore.

I chose this route as a more granular alternative to TimeMachine and to show my boss I could write AppleScript :>)

Any help gratefully received.

All the best

John

Comment: Have you checked your 'Volumes' path? Path names usually does'nt contain the server name. I would go for (if not (exists POSIX file "/Volumes/computer-backup/Web") then make new folder with properties {name:"Web"} at "computer-backup")

Comment: You, sir, are right on the money. Stupid mistake by me. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked your 'Volumes' path? Path names usually does'nt contain the server name. I would go for (if not (exists POSIX file "/Volumes/computer-backup/Web") then make new folder with properties {name:"Web"} at "computer-backup") –  tompaman Dec 27 '13 at 13:35